# How to read non-contiguous excel cells as a vector in r using readxl package?

Tags: r, readxl

I want to read some non-contiguous cells from a excel sheet using the readxl package. The data read in should be stored as a vector.

The cells I am reading in are in date format and I want to keep that format.

I have tried the following:

```
  startDate <- c(read_excel("G:/ai/My Courses/Course Distributions.xlsm", sheet = "Academic Calendar",  col_names = F, range = "c7"),
             read_excel("G:/ai/My Courses/Course Distributions.xlsm", sheet = "Academic Calendar", col_names = F, range = "d7"),
             read_excel("G:/ai/My Courses/Course Distributions.xlsm", sheet = "Academic Calendar", col_names = F, range = "e7"),
                 read_excel("G:/ai/My Courses/Course Distributions.xlsm", sheet = "Academic Calendar", col_names = F, range = "f7"))
```

My results are

```
> startDate 
$`X__1`
[1] "2018-01-15 UTC"

$X__1
[1] "2018-08-30 UTC"

$X__1
[1] "2018-10-15 UTC"

$X__1
[1] "2018-11-15 UTC"
```

How can I get the result as a vector?

Comment: `unlist(startDate)`?

Comment: unlist(startDate) seems to breaks down the date structure. I get >unlist(startDate)
      X__1       X__1       X__1       X__1 
1515974400 1535587200 1539561600 1542240000. Alternatively i am using, startDate <- c(startDate[[1]], startDate[[2]], startDate[[3]], startDate[[4]]), which keeps the date structure.